Create Ranking Chart in Google Looker Studio
I have some issues creating a visualization to display ranking in Google Looker Studio.
The question was: Please rank the following aspects of choosing a distribution partner from most important to least important. So number 1 would be most important, and number 9 least important.

It does not show all values on the Y asis. I can't understand why.
It does not show correct count on each value.
I have tried in both ways to display the data.
enter image description here

It would show up like this: enter image description here
And I tried also in transposed versionenter image description here
But it shows up like this enter image description here And it only shows 6 values on the Y asis (instead of 9).
I'd like to have it count amount of time 1 metric has been give number 1 or 2 etc..
How can I create this? This is how it would show on Microsoft forms.
enter image description here
But I need to create this in Google looker Studio as Microsoft forms are not crossfiltering and they are not interactive.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask] and how to create a [mre]. From [tag:google-sheets]: "Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data. Use markdown TEXT tables instead. Use this tag for questions about programmatically interacting with Google Sheets." Thus, show how this question is related to programming and, if so, add the data and code as text.
